# Why is this benchmark code using such high CPU?

Tags: c, linux, posix, poll-syscall

The code below works, it's sending all the correct data, and it's receiving the correct data.

When I use it to benchmark a very fast server, the benchmark's CPU usage is ~10%. However, when I benchmark a slow server, that rises to ~50% – the same as the server I'm benchmarking/stress testing*.

That is going by what `top`'s reporting.

Why would it use so much CPU? I suspect I'm misusing poll, but I'm not sure how?

The CPU time for the slow server is 4x that of the benchmark, while for the fast server it is 7x that of the benchmark.

```
int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
assert(flags != -1);
assert(fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) != -1);

int32 red = 0;
struct pollfd pollfd = {
    .fd = sockfd,
    .events = POLLIN | POLLOUT
};
do {
    assert(poll(&pollfd, 1, -1) == 1);
    if (pollfd.revents & POLLOUT) {
        int n;
        while ((n = send(sockfd, buf__+bufOffset, bufLength-bufOffset, MSG_NOSIGNAL)) > 0) {
            bufOffset += n;
            if (n != bufLength-bufOffset)
                break;
        }
        assert(!(n == -1 && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK));
    }

    if (pollfd.revents & POLLIN) {
        int r;
        while ((r = read(sockfd, recvBuf, MIN(recvLength-red, recvBufLength))) > 0) {
            // assert(memcmp(recvBuf, recvExpectedBuf+red, r) == 0);
            red += r;
            if (r != MIN(recvLength-red, recvBufLength))
                break;
        }
        assert(!(r == -1 && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK));
    }
} while (bufOffset < bufLength);

assert(fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags & ~O_NONBLOCK) != -1);
int r;
while ((r = read(sockfd, recvBuf, MIN(recvLength-red, recvBufLength))) > 0) {
    // assert(memcmp(recvBuf, recvExpectedBuf+red, r) == 0);
    red += r;
}
assert(fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) != -1);

assert(red == recvLength);

int r = read(sockfd, recvBuf, 1);
assert((r == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) || r == 0);
```

<sub>* (I'm running both benchmark and server on the same machine, for now. Communication is over TCP.)</sub>

Comment: I don't really understand the question... If you've a more powerful computer, it's obvious it will handle high volume data easier than a low-end computer. Which can end to: Finishing faster on the "high-perf" computer or finishing at "once" but using more CPU on low-perf.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán It's all on the same computer, all on the same CPU core. The only difference between the "slow server" and the "fast server" is that one is a bulky slow codebase with a lot of overhead, and one is my new, lightweight rewrite.

Comment: does the server answer only after a full message? if so...

Comment: `.revents = POLLIN | POLLOUT` you're not supposed to set that, also instead of a `do-while` just make it a `while(poll(pollfd,...))` loop better.  Also, AFAIK `POLLIN` means you need to read, not write, the same goes for `POLLOUT`.

Comment: @user9000 I'm setting it, and using a `do...while`, because it's almost guaranteed to be read/writable the first time through the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest using libevent instead of handling this by yourself, it can get tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are busy-waiting. If the `read` and `write` return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` you are calling them continuously. Add a `select` which will wait until the socket is ready for reading or writing before that.

Comment: I don't think I am, the `while` loops only continue when their return values are > 0, and then there's the poll in the `do...while` loop.

Comment: Right, but that will return when the fd is ready for read OR ready for write. You want a separate wait before each one. I'd use `select` but `poll` is I suppose fine.

Comment: I've just updated the code to take that into account, alas, still 50% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It wasn't misrepresented CPU usage exactly. The inefficient server was sending 8 byte packages with TCP_NODELAY, so I was receiving millions of poll notifications to read just 8 bytes. It turns out the read(2) call was rather expensive, and calling it tens of thousands of times per second was enough to see "time spent in system mode" rocket to ~56%, which was added to "time spent in user mode" to produce the very high CPU usage.

Comment: Complete nonsense. If your process is blocked in `poll`, it won't count as anything but idle.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley What led me to conclude that was that I can run 10 instances of the benchmark simultaneously, and their reported CPU usage each goes down. So the server will be consuming ~50%, and each of the benchmarks will be consuming ~5%. I cannot fathom any explanation which would account for this, other than roughly the above.

Comment: Since you're running client and server on the same machine, there are no network delays. If the server isn't blocking on any task other than writing to the client, there's no reason to expect the total CPU usage to be less than 100%. And if the server doesn't need a lot of CPU to generate the responses it sends to the client, then there's no reason not to expect the division to be 50% server and 50% divided among clients. So what *did* you expect, and why?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley The server's doing an order of magnitude more work than the client. The efficiently-written server shows a CPU time of 7x that of the client. The inefficiently-written server shows a CPU time of 4x that of the client (despite both server and client showing ~50% in `top`). Given the overhead of the inefficiently-written server, I would expect that to be closer to 70x.

Comment: Where do your 7x and 4x numbers come from?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Looking at the CPU time according to `top`.

Comment: I thought top was where you got 50%/50%. Where did that come from?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley `top` reports both 50%/50%, and the 7x and 4x cpu time numbers. As in, I start client and the slow server, both have consistently 45-55% CPU, but the server clocks up CPU time 4x faster than the client. When I start the client and the fast server, the client's ~12%, server ~88%, and CPU time increases about 7x faster for the server.

Answer (score 0):

So if I finally understood this, you're comparing the ratio of `%CPU` reported by top to the ratio of the rate of increase of `TIME+` reported by top, and they don't agree. (It would have been easier if you said which columns you were reading from!) As far as I can tell both are calculated from the same fields in the underlying `/proc` data, so it shouldn't be possible for them to disagree by much.

And I can't replicate it. I've put your code into a test program and run it with no modifications other than fixing a redeclaration of `int r` compilation error and adding what I believe to be reasonable declarations for all the stuff you left out. I connected it to a server that reads lines from the client and eats a little bit of CPU after each one before sending a line back. The result was that top showed `%CPU` around 99 for the server and 2 for the client and about a 50-to-1 ratio in the `TIME+` column.

I find nothing wrong with the use of `poll`.

I don't like your use of `assert` though - when assertions are turned off the program is going to be missing a lot of important syscalls.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Wumpus. I rewrote it using epoll, only to have the same issue. I then started timing how long is spent in each section, and realised it was iterating the `do...while` loop more than I thought it should. The slow server was outputting 8 byte packages, on every single one I was notified, and for every single one I was calling read(2). The system overhead of read is what led to the high CPU time.